# How to sync two postgresql databases in real time

Tags: database, postgresql, synchronization

I have two postgresql databases configured for replication. Master node is sending new data in real time to secondary node and it works just fine. But there is one disadvantage - secondary node is read-only, so no write requests are accepted.

What I need is to be able to perform write/read operations on both of the databases and still be able to have them in perfect sync, so they are identical.

What is the best solution for such requirements?

Just for the context of this question:
I have two web app instances that are deployed in two different locations in the world (very high delay in sending requests is the reason I decided to deploy one instance locally in each location). Both instances are fetching the same data but they are also able to generate some data and input it into the DB. It is impossible to have only one DB due to too big delay when fetching data.

Maybe my solution is not perfect, I'm open for any suggestion really because I'm out of ideas how to make it work smoothly and maybe I'm lacking some knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: There are only commercial closed-source solutions for multi-master replication. And you will have to deal with replication conflicts that will undo committed transactions. I wouldn't recommend going that way. You could use streaming replication and use the master database for all writes - if there are not too many changes, the latency might be tolerable. Read from a local replica.

Comment: I actually did that, I am routing writes to master node and reads to secondary, but I faced another problem. For example lets assume I have a simple text I want to edit on the frontend and as a response for POST request I will get updated text on the frontend. I am sending edited text as write operation to master node, change is done and response on the backend is generated fetching data from secondary DB which at this time is not yet synced with master DB. As a result I am getting old data on the frontend and have to reload the page to get the new, updated text.

Comment: That is unavoidable unless you use synchronous replication (which would be even worse in your case). You could change your code to use `UPDATE ... RETURNING` for data modifications, or you could direct read requests that query values that were recently changed to the primary server.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the solution I need. I am using django as a backend framework and I was wondering if I can simply wait until data is finished synchronizing and only then return a response but I have no idea how to do it and if it is even possible. And even with such solution I would have to change the code of every view function I have in my app

Comment: You could try synchronous replication with `synchronous_commit = remote_apply`. But that only has a chance if a) you have *very few* data modifications and b) there are no long-running queries.

Comment: What should happen if one person makes a post on one server at the exact same time another person makes a post on another server?

Comment: Actually sync replication pretty much solved my problem. Thanks! I tested it and delays turned out to be acceptable and previous problem disappeared. There is one drawback though, I'm concerned about the situation when  secondary will be down for some reason, master won't process any transaction until secondary is up again or someone manually switch master to async replication.

Comment: @user253751   This is some corner case that I don't expect to happen in my setup however I was hoping that there is some solution out there that could handle such conflicts. In my case if such thing happen I could even accept it if server would return some kind of bad request to the end user to force him to post changes again

Comment: @cable2360 in order to return a bad request, the request has to wait until it talks to both servers. If it doesn't wait for both servers to answer, then one server won't know whether the corner case is happening, until after the response is already sent. This is why multi-master replication is hard and not many people use it.

Comment: so how such high availability should be properly solved, if you want to deploy an app in different parts of the world and have decent delay loading requests?